# NodeJs : fs.appendFileSync does not accept a number type in data argument node v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

**Version: 14.1.0
Platform: Windows 10
Subsystem: none**

> ```
> > error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be
> > of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView.
> > Received type number (7) this is the code:
> ```

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.writeFileSync('notes.txt', 'NODEJS')


fs.appendFileSync('notes.txt', 7 )
```

I expected to get a file with: NODEJS7
I got : NODEJS

**THIS WAS WORKING IN THE PREVIOUS VERSIONS CORRECTLY!!!!!!**

Comment: ok then whats the problem passing down the number as string ?

Comment: Why do you just do this: `fs.appendFileSync('notes.txt', (7).toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fs.appendFileSync does not accept number type anymore.

you could pass it as a template string if you have a variable, or you could use the `to.String()` method.